# docker-compose volume not mounting correctly

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am following the flask/docker tutorial on [testdriven.io](http://testdriven.io). Within Part One on the third section [Docker Config](http://testdriven.io/part-one-docker-config/) I am following the instructions in order to mount the project directory as a volume within the docker container for development. Unfortunately following the instructions in the tutorial does not mount the volume correctly with docker-compose. Instead the directory inside the container is empty.

The following is the *Dockerfile* for the container in question.

```
FROM python:3.6.1

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add requirements (to leverage Docker cache)
ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
ADD . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD python manage.py runserver -h 0.0.0.0
```

And this is the *docker-compose.yml* file

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  users-service:
    container_name: users-service
    build: .
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000 # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
```

The directory in question is the /usr/src/app directory inside the users-service container. When I do:

```
>> docker-compose build 
>> docker-compose up -d
>> docker-compose run users-service bash
```

When I `ls` inside the container I am in the correct directory (/usr/src/app) but the directory is empty. This also causes the CMD to fail as it can't find the manage.py file which is in the root of the project directory.

I've seen other posts on stack-overflow with similar titles, unfortunately none of the solutions have been able to solve my problem. I've tried changing the local volume path  from relative to absolute with no difference in result.Thank you in advance for anybody who is able to help a fellow out.

EDIT:

Having run `docker inspect` on the container, below is the information found under `Mounts` and `Config` - `Volume`:

```
"Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/home/jonathan/projects/flask-microservices-users",
                "Destination": "/usr/src/app",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
 ...
 "Config": {
        ...
        "Image": "flaskmicroservicesusers_users-service",
        "Volumes": {
            "/usr/src/app": {}
        },
        "WorkingDir": "/usr/src/app",
        ...
```

Comment: what's in the directory you're mounting? `.` is it not empty?

Comment: The directory I'm mounting is the root directory for the project.

`me@ubuntu:~/project$ ls
Dockerfile manage.py README.md docker-compose.yml
project requirements.txt`

Comment: can you do docker inspect on your user-service container and check what volumes it has?

Comment: Unfortunately the container doesn't stay running. Without the volume being mounted properly, the manage.py file and project directory are missing inside the container so it does not persist when run.

Comment: but you can still run inspect on stopped container

Comment: Right you are. I have edited my original post with the results of a `docker inspect`

Comment: Oh, so you sure you don't have typos in your paths? you gave ls from `~/project` yet the inspect has `/home/jonathan/projects/` there is an __s__ there, docker will readily create the dirs on your host if they are missing...

Comment: I was going for brevity in my comment above. The actual path I used was:

`jonathan@ubuntu:~/projects/flask-microservices-users$ ls`

Comment: do you have selinux enabled? I think this may give you some trouble...

Comment: another problem may be your rprivate propagation, have you got any funny mount arrangement in your home dir?

Comment: I've checked selinux, it's disabled. I'm running off a fresh install of ubuntu 16.04 LTS so there shouldn't be any mount arrangements going on.

Comment: Hmm this is very peculiar, never had problems like that with volumes, the last thing that springs to mind is overriding volumes, but maybe try to move your stuff to a different place or mount additional path from your host to container and check that out - then you know that there is not a general issue getting in a way. Strip it down imho as it's hard to debug for the obvious 'aha' moments ;) (also absolute > relative imho)

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you can't mount a volume to an existing path in the container and expect the data within that path to be syncd. This is not how unix volume mounts work.

An explanation can be found here:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32203

Have a look here if you need to make data inside a container persistent:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4361#issuecomment-36317097

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following from your *Dockerfile*:

```
# add app
ADD . /usr/src/app
```

Review the answer here for more info:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27753725/1799408

Comment: Hi Michael, thank you for your advice, unfortunately it hasn't solved the problem. Even after clearing the docker cache and starting from scratch. I've edited my original comment to include the results of a `docker compose` on the container.